# Acceder a base de datos mediante requests

Tags: python, python-requests

resulta que en el trabajo me han pedido que acceda a una base de datos y extraiga diferentes datos para analizarlos. Lo cual no he hecho jamás.

Entiendo que lo primero que debo hacer es acceder al servidor poniendo mi usuario y contraseña. Para ello me dieron un link similar a este:

https://xxx.zzz.es:15532/api/external/login?username=usuario&password=password/

A lo cual entiendo que debo acceder mediante la librería `requests` empleando los conceptos de `get`y `post`.

Al ver el link, (y no entender muy bien cómo hacerlo si no) mi idea fue sustituir directamente en el enlace mi usuario y contraseña(usuario=usu, password=pas) y a partir de allí ver el comportamiento. Pues cuando la url es https://google.es/ me da un valor 200 y por lo tanto se que todo  ha ido bien.

Tengo un primer código como el siguiente:

```
import requests

url = 'https://xxx.zzz.es:15532/api/external/login?username=usu&password=pas/'

def main():
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Tot be')
    else:
        print('Ha habido un problema', response.status_code)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

No funciona, me da error de que no se hace así, ¿alguien me podría decir o al menos orientar que debo leer para aprender a hacer esto correctamente?

> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx.zzz.es', port=15532): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /api/external/login?username=usu&password=pas/
>   (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
>   local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))

Comment: Ese error es debido a un fallo en la verificación del certificado porque estas accediendo a traves de HTTPS. Si pruebas `requests.get(url, verify=false) te sale el mismo error?

Comment: Ya no falla el programa y me da un error 401. Yo entiendo que estoy haciéndolo mal y debería mandar las credenciales de alguna manera, no? Gracias!

Comment: Sin saber mucho más sobre el endpoint no sabría decirte bien. El error 401 dice que no te estas autentificando correctamente. Hay varias formas de autenficarse con requests aqui [https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/authentication/] Prueba las dos primeras opciones a ver si alguna te sirve

Comment: Sin saber mucho del tema, creo que no se debe pasar el usuario y clave por la url. Cambia la url a url = 'https://xxx.zzz.es:15532/api/external/login' añade args = {'username':'usuario','password':'pas'} y luego modifica la linea del get por response = requests.get(url, params=args)

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace da el mismo error

Comment: @NEA la autenticación depende de la API, algunas veces se mandan los credenciales via params, otras veces se necesita un token, etc.

Comment: y si accedes directamente a la api por el navegador te autentifica correctamente? Prueba también con "Postman", es un programa que te ayuda a enviar y recibir peticiones POST, GET, PUT, etc... para probar APIs manualmente

Comment: Te refieres a que si pongo la url que he puesto en post si me funciona? De ser si la respuesta es no, me da un error 401. Entiendo que no meto los datos correctamente

Comment: Entonces habla con el responsable del endpoint y que te dé toda la documentación de la API, sino vas a perder el tiempo o revisa otra vez que tus credenciales sean correctas